# Google cloud platform: permission denied when using gpu monitoring

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I found no question regarding this issue. I'm trying to add a gpu monitoring to my vm instance, following the instructions here: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/monitor-gpus. Yet when I tried to enable the gpu agent, I got this error: `/lib/systemd/system/gpu_utilization_agent.service: Permission denied.`
Anyone has encountered this issue before or know how to resolve? What is really denying my access to what?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you run [these steps](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/monitor-gpus#setup-script) in [cloud shell](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/launching-cloud-shell#launching_from_the_console), it needs to run these steps [on your VM](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-instance#gcloud)s.

You can try following [this article](https://medium.com/@devops_83824/enabling-custom-gpu-metrics-in-stackdriver-for-google-cloud-platform-78067af32b92) created by Medium on "Enabling custom GPU metrics in Stackdriver for Google Cloud Platform" which might be a good place to look over for more details and [Adding or removing GPUs document](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/add-gpus#setup-script).

Comment: Thanks for your response! But I am indeed running on my VM, and I also followed the article. Everything worked until I got permission denied at the "Enabling GPU metrics agent" part. Any other insights? Thanks!

Comment: You can [verify Compute Engine credentials](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/troubleshooting#verify-creds) and [verify default service account permission](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/troubleshooting#verifying_default_service_account_permission).

Answer (score 0):

I got same problem and had solved.

You may check the permission of /lib/systemd/system/

```
$ ls -ld /lib/systemd/system/
drwxr-xr-x 22 root root 36864 Nov  6 09:49 /lib/systemd/system/
```

So you need write permission temporarily. Because you are going to write /lib/systemd/system/gpu_utilization_agent.service

```
sudo chmod 777 /lib/systemd/system
```

After writing gpu_utilization_agent.service, you can change back the permission.

```
sudo chmod 755 /lib/systemd/system
```

And you may need sudo to run systemctl.

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl --no-reload --now enable /lib/systemd/system/gpu_utilization_agent.service
```